# Why is Q embedded in a field if the field is of characteristic zero?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I was reading:

http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf

On page 8

Where it states (and I have changed the wording and added content for better understanding)

> Let $\phi :  \Bbb{Z} \rightarrow F$ be a function from the integers to a field F defined by: $\phi(n) =  \underbrace{1_F+ 1_F + ... 1_F}_{n \ times}$
> It follows naturally that $\phi$ is a homomorphism from the additive group of $\Bbb{Z}$ to the additive group on the field.
>
> My first question is how to show that $\phi$ is a homomorphism over the multiplicative ring structure of $\Bbb{Z}$ to $F$. It's not clear how the additive group homomorphism implies this.
>
> Continuing, if $\ker(\phi)=  0$ it follows that only $0 \in \Bbb{Z}$ gets mapped $0_F$ and therefore every non-zero element $u \in \Bbb{Z}$ gets mapped to an invertible element of $F$. But somehow the book makes the jump:
>
> Nonzero integers map to invertible elements of F under $n \rightarrow n*1_F$  and so this map extends to a homomorphism
> $$ \frac{m}{n} \rightarrow (m \times 1_F)(n \times 1_F)^{-1} $$
> Implying that $Q \subset F$

Now I think that last statement is a big jump, Especially given that it isn't clear the homomorphism is even defined for division, given that its original domain was just the integers. Showing it is a homomorphism of multiplication certainly help, but that still doesn't show at all how to define it for fractional values, let alone showing that those fractional values map to the clean field counterparts. What am I to make of this? Can someone rigorously, but using only machinery available to a first year abstract algebra beginner, explain this?

Comment: $1_F = f(1) = f(1/n + 1/n \dots 1/n) = nf(1/n)$ for any function $f$ such that $f$ restricted to $\Bbb Z$ is $\phi$. This shows that $f(1/n) = 1/n$. Then show that $f(m/n) = m/n$ and you are done. I have omitted the subsript $F$ for elements in the range - should still be clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Showing that $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism is basically combinatorics. You have
$$
\phi(m)\phi(n)=(\underbrace{1_F+\dots+1_F}_{m\textrm{ times}})(\underbrace{1_F+\dots+1_F}_{n\textrm{ times}})
$$
Since the distributive law holds in fields, you can multiply these sums together in the usual way, giving $mn$ copies of $1_F(1_F)=1_F$. (If you wanted to be extremely careful, you could write this out as an induction proof, but this is the way you should think about it.)

The last step doesn't require that the homomorphism be defined for fractional values. (In fact, the point is to tell you how to define it for fractional values.) It only requires that it be defined for the *integers* $m$ and $n$, with $n$ nonzero. This allows us to consider the field element
$$
\phi(m)[\phi(n)]^{-1}
$$
and then showing the map $\frac{m}{n} \mapsto \phi(m)[\phi(n)]^{-1}$ is a well-defined homomorphism of rings from $\Bbb{Q}$ to $F$ is essentially a matter of writing down definitions.

Comment: Yes, but... If you want to write down careful precise proofs of the whole business of showing that this $\phi$ is a ring morphism, it gets extremely tiresome. This is the sort of thing that every mathematician should do once in life, and come to the satisfaction that it indeed can be done.